# Plotly: How to set an interval of '10' on both the axis where the range is as follows [0,100]

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, scatter-plot, plotly-python

How to set an interval of '10' on both the axis where the range is as follows [0,100]

[image: Plotly Pic for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the starting tick and tick spacing like this (using some sample data that has a similar range to yours):

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[0,105],y=[20,102], mode='markers'))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'linear',
        tick0 = -10,
        dtick = 10
    ),
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'linear',
        tick0 = 0,
        dtick = 10
    )
)
```

[image]